# Selenium Error (Java)- Frame is detected but prompted noSuchFrameException when attempting to switch to it

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

**Issue Description:**

I am unable to switch to a particular frame via Chrome v92, despite doing so easily via Firefox.

**Code Sample:**

```
@Test
    void auto_015_5() {
        int bet = 7;        
        driver.navigate().to("https://boademo.com/"); 
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        List < WebElement > counters = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='counter']"));
        counters.get(0).click();     
        List < WebElement > marketOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='au-target market-option row nowrap can-place-bets']"));
        for (int i = 0; i <= (bet * 3) - 1; i += 3) {
            WebElement currentOption = marketOptions.get(i);
            JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            if (i % 6 == 0 && i >= 6) {
                je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", marketOptions.get(i - 6));
            }
            currentOption.click();
        }
        
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    }
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Navigate to [Link](https://boademo.com/)

Switch to the necessary frame `(className = 'boa-iframe')`

Choose any sporting Event from the `'Matches' Lobby.`

Select ANY market to prompt the bet coupon `(bottom-right).`

Switch to default Content.

Attempt to switch to the bet coupon's frame `(className = 'boa-overlay-iframe')`

```
NoSuchFrameException()
```

[html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg0sQ.png)

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried so far ? and what is the error ?

Comment: Error is no such frame

Comment: What is `rt.acceptPopUp();` specially `rt` ?

Comment: Left it there by accident, nothing important. RT is the object which instantiates my TestRunner class. acceptPopUp just clicks the accept button on the popup

Comment: Please see below, It does work in my local. I hope it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can switch to `iframe` with the help of Explicit waits.
2. Indexing is not prefer.

**Sample code :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://boademo.com/");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.button-agree"))).click();
int bet = 7;        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.boa-iframe")));
List < WebElement > counters = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='counter']"));
counters.get(0).click();     
List < WebElement > marketOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='au-target market-option row nowrap can-place-bets']"));
for (int i = 0; i <= (bet * 3) - 1; i += 3) {
    WebElement currentOption = marketOptions.get(i);
    JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
       if (i % 6 == 0 && i >= 6) {
            je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", marketOptions.get(i - 6));
        }
        currentOption.click();
    }
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='boa-overlay-iframe']")));
System.out.println("You are inside boa-overlay-iframe");
```

Comment: The code does indeed work for me, however my problem is that I am unable to switch to the iframe of className = 'boa-overlay-iframe'.

Comment: Where is this iframe ? Does that come after `counters.get(0).click();` ?

Comment: Yes. It contains the bet coupon displayed on the bottom right

Comment: @NickBorg :  Updated above at the bottom of the code, let me know if it works.

Comment: unfortunately no...  org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: By.cssSelector: iframe[class='boa-overlay-iframe'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: strange the same code works perfectly in my local.

Comment: perhaps a problem with my chromedriver version? I dont understand why it happens to me. I am using selenium version 3.141.59, Chromedriver version 93.0.4577.15

Comment: I am using latest version, you can also try to update it to latest and see if that helps

Comment: I am using selenium version 3.141.59, Chromedriver version 93.0.4577.15

Comment: Sounds latest to me. Are you getting the same exception ?

Comment: When I attempt to switch to the 'boa-overlay-frame' via Chrome or Edge it never works regardless of which method I try to use. On the other hand it works perfectly on FireFox. No one seems to be having the same issue as I do and I can't understand why.

Comment: I get the same exception, yes

Comment: This is more shocking cause I ran my test on chromdriver not on gecko

Comment: If the problem is not from the code, nor from the driver or the selenium version..what could it be?